# How to create my own datasets using in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset

I want to create my own datasets, and use it in scikit-learn. Scikit-learn has some datasets like 'The Boston Housing Dataset' (.csv), user can use it by:

```
from sklearn import datasets 
boston = datasets.load_boston()
```

and codes below can get the `data` and `target` of this dataset:

```
X = boston.data
y = boston.target
```

The question is how to create my own dataset and can be used in that way? 
Any answers is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the data? Like csv or text or something similar?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to use your own data, do you want other people to be able to use your data, or do you want to create artificial data?

Comment: @Vivek Kumar, yes, I created a small dataset in Demo.csv before, and now I just think should I create two .csv folders to store the data and target respectively?

Comment: @ kazemakase, hi, sorry for misunderstanding, I want to use my own data which collected from some experiments by myself.

Comment: Ok. What do you want to do with the data.. Perform machine learning?  Which kind?

Comment: @ Vivek Kumar, yes, I want to use the data in machine learning, linear regression

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick and dirty way to achieve what you intend:

##### `my_datasets.py`

```py
import numpy as np
import csv
from sklearn.utils import Bunch

def load_my_fancy_dataset():
    with open(r'my_fancy_dataset.csv') as csv_file:
        data_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        feature_names = next(data_reader)[:-1]
        data = []
        target = []
        for row in data_reader:
            features = row[:-1]
            label = row[-1]
            data.append([float(num) for num in features])
            target.append(int(label))
        
        data = np.array(data)
        target = np.array(target)
    return Bunch(data=data, target=target, feature_names=feature_names)
```

##### `my_fancy_dataset.csv`

```
feature_1,feature_2,feature_3,class_label
5.9,1203,0.69,2
7.2,902,0.52,0
6.3,143,0.44,1
-2.6,291,0.15,1
1.8,486,0.37,0
```

##### Demo

```py
In [12]: import my_datasets

In [13]: mfd = my_datasets.load_my_fancy_dataset()

In [14]: X = mfd.data

In [15]: y = mfd.target

In [16]: X
Out[16]: 
array([[ 5.900e+00,  1.203e+03,  6.900e-01],
       [ 7.200e+00,  9.020e+02,  5.200e-01],
       [ 6.300e+00,  1.430e+02,  4.400e-01],
       [-2.600e+00,  2.910e+02,  1.500e-01],
       [ 1.800e+00,  4.860e+02,  3.700e-01]])

In [17]: y
Out[17]: array([2, 0, 1, 1, 0])

In [18]: mfd.feature_names
Out[18]: ['feature_1', 'feature_2', 'feature_3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data loaded into memory as a 2D array, there is an easy way to do this with [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder):

```py
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data = [['Male', 1, True], ['Female', 3, True], ['Female', 2, False], ['Male', 2, False]]
y = [0, 1, 1, 1]  # expected outputs
enc = OneHotEncoder(drop='if_binary')  # create encoder obj that drops unneeded columns on binary inputs
X = enc.fit_transform(data).toarray()  # vectorize input data
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)  # create classifier obj
clf.fit(X[:-1], y[:-1])  # fit model using training data (all but last entry)

out = clf.predict(X[-1:])  # resulting prediction (last entry only)
```