# Creating a brand-new Scikit-Learn Dataset out of a CSV with string variables

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, opencsv

After looking this up, I found a possible solution to my problem in: [How to transform my csv file into this scikit learn dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090837/how-to-transform-my-csv-file-into-this-scikit-learn-dataset)

However, the colleague's question never implied categorical variables and so whenever I try to implement this code I find this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Adzuki beans, uncooked'
```

My code so far:

```
def load_my_dataset():
    with open('data/Composition3_remastered') as csv_file:
        data_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
        temp = next(data_file)
        n_samples = 1878 #number of data rows, don't count header
        n_features = 14 #number of columns for features, don't count target column
        feature_names = ['Food Item','f2','f3','f4'] #adjust accordingly
        target_names = ['t1','t2','t3'] #adjust accordingly
        data = np.empty((n_samples, n_features))
        target = np.empty((n_samples,), dtype=np.int)

        for i, sample in enumerate(data_file):
            data[i] = np.asarray(sample[:-1])
            target[i] = np.asarray(sample[-1])

    return Bunch(data=data, target=target, feature_names = feature_names, target_names = target_names)

data6 = load_my_dataset()
```

Note that I actually have 2 categorical variables: Food Item and Food Category.

How could I sort this out?

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback in the question.  (Surely there's a better way to populate the array than line by line?)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to disclose a bit more about what you plan to do with data. For regression tasks, you'd have to encode categorical variables, and its as simple as adding this

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

oh = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
oh.fit(data)
```

The column names will be preserved when you feed them into feature names. But since you're using sklearn methods to preprocess data, it may be wise to look into using Pipelines that will enable you to fit imputation, data transformations, scaling and other tasks that are generally required before pushing data into the ML engine.

Comment: I need to do a PCA of two components!