# Why are full stops appearing in the printed statement of an array?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am currently learning how to use python and jupyter notebook. I want to create my own dataset. The code for that is as follows (which was taken from this website: [How to create my own datasets using in scikit-learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432850/how-to-create-my-own-datasets-using-in-scikit-learn)):

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from sklearn.datasets.base import Bunch

def load_movies_dataset():
    with open('Documents/movies_dataset.csv') as csv_file:
        data_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
        temp = next(data_file)
        n_samples = int(temp[0])
        n_features = int(temp[1])
        data = np.empty((n_samples, n_features))
        target = np.empty((n_samples,), dtype=np.int)

    for i, sample in enumerate(data_file):
        data[i] = np.asarray(sample[:-1], dtype=np.int)
        target[i] = np.asarray(sample[-1], dtype=np.int)

return Bunch(data=data, target=target)
```

This is the csv file that I'm using:

```
"6","2","numKicks","numKisses"
"3","104","0"
"2","100","0"
"1","81","0"
"101","10","1"
"99","5","1"
"98","2","1"
```

This example determines if a movie is a romance(0) or action(1) based on the number of kicks and number of kisses.

This is the code I'm using to test the creation of the dataset:

```
md = load_movies_dataset()
X = md.data
y = md.target
X
```

And this is the output:

```
array([[  3., 104.],
   [  2., 100.],
   [  1.,  81.],
   [101.,  10.],
   [ 99.,   5.],
   [ 98.,   2.]])
```

My question is, why are there full stops in the array display?

Answer (score 0):

They are decimal points. It is an array of floats:

```
>>> x
array([[  3., 104.],
       [  2., 100.],
       [  1.,  81.],
       [101.,  10.],
       [ 99.,   5.],
       [ 98.,   2.]])
>>> y
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
>>> x.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>>
```

---

The default data-type for [`numpy.empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html#numpy.empty) is `numpy.float64`.

Comment: Thank you @wwii. I have changed the code to: data = np.empty((n_samples, n_features), dtype=np.int) and it gives me the correct results.